# Is load() called implicitly when using a method from an std::atomic?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++14, atomic, c++17

I've noticed that, at least on the surface, the last lines of code seem to be equivalent:

```
std::atomic<int*> a;
a.store(new int{11});
std::cout << *a.load() << "\n";
std::cout << *a << "\n";
```

It seems that the value stored inside an atomic wrapper over a pointer can be accessed by calling the dereference operator directly or by loading the pointer and then calling the operator.

Is there a difference between the two ? Is the usage of the dereference operator implicitly calling load() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a` has `operator int*()` called on it, and then the indirection operator is applied to the pointer. The conversion function is the same as calling `load`, so they're nearly identical.

The only difference would be if the type was user defined because it would consume your one user-defined implicit conversion.

Comment: Wait... what exactly do you mean by the fact that a has the operator int*() called on it and then the indirection operator... aren't those exactly the same thing, is what you're saying that the line of code is interpreted as **a (doesn't seem to be the case) ? I had assume load is called implicitly because a doesn't have the operator "*" but a.load() does... but now I'm more confused

Comment: @George `operator*()` is the indirection operator, `operator int*()` is a conversion operator. `operator int*()` calls `load()` and returns the `int*`, which has the `*` used on it.